# vb.net. play file from selected item

Tags: vb.net

im make a music box from an old pc. 
Im trying to get the selected song from listbox1 to play when hitting the play button. All songs have a genre category. Form 1 has buttons to choose which genre and when clicked it opens another form with a listbox. For example on form 2(the genre for this form is country), The listbox is set to search in "C:/newfiles/country/" And any songs in the folder are shown on the list box.
The problem is im trying to get the program to play the selected song from the listbox without having to set each song's directory.

The reason im trying to make the program this way is so that i can just add/delete songs from a directory and not have to set/delete directories from the program.

Code:
Public Class Form2

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ' make a reference to a directory
    Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo("c:\newfiles\Country\")
    Dim diar1 As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
    Dim dra As IO.FileInfo

    'list the names of all files in the specified directory
    For Each dra In diar1
        ListBox1.Items.Add(dra)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub backButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles backButton1.Click
    Me.Close()
    Form1.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub PlayButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PlayButton1.Click
 ?



End Sub

Private Function AxWindowsMediaPlayer1() As Object
    Throw New NotImplementedException
End Function
```

End Class

Comment: I cant get the song play. Any ideas?

Comment: Always show the code that duplicates the problem for us.

Comment: @LarsTech Code is there now.

Comment: Create a variable for your path: `Private musicPath As String = "c:\newfiles\Country\"`, then use the Path class to recreate the full path: `Path.Combine(musicPath, ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString)`  Make sure the SelectedIndex of the ListBox is not -1.

Comment: path is not declared, did you mean musicpath.combine?

Comment: No.  Path is in the IO namespace.  It returns a file path for you to use.

Comment: Were do i find the Path class? Sorry new to vb.net

Comment: `Dim s As String = IO.Path.Combine(...`

Comment: Ok thank you problem fixed!

Comment: How do set this thread as solved/closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my comments, declare a variable for your file path:

```
Private musicPath As String = "c:\newfiles\Country"
```

then use the Path class to combine your music path and file name:

```
If ListBox1.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
  Dim s As String = IO.Combine(musicPath, ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString)
  ' do something with s
End If
```